# Menu shortcuts and MDI in Windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu, mdi

After I modified my application to the MDI application (main form became an MDI container), all of the shortcuts, which were specified int the main menu of the original form, are no longer works. What can I do in order to "turn them on" again?

Comment: Or maybe be some other reasons could cause this problem. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: What about them doesn't work? How are they setup? What do they do?

Comment: There are two child forms. Each of them contains panel(used for drawing and manipulating graphical content). The problem arises when a panel get focused.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is that you need to set the [mdiparent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent.aspx) property of any child form before you show it.  You could have missed this when you switched the main form over.